# How to install hugin in ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)

Tags: 22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed and I would like to install `hugin`. Unfortunately, this package doesn't seem to be available for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS yet.
Does anyone know if `hugin` will be available for Ubuntu 22.04. Or can anyone tell me how to install `hugin` in ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I think the best you can do is to approach the developer and pose your question there... http://hugin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

Panda Jim made it available in one of his ppa repositories.
Ref on his blog https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/hugin-panorama-stitcher-ubuntu-22-04/

To install `hugin` just do :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
sudo apt install hugin
```

Answer (score 3):

The precompiled AppImage crashes on my computer, and I don't know how to run auxiliary programs from AppImages.  So I am using the [FlatHub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/net.sourceforge.Hugin) version.

You will need flatpak:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

Then install hugin:

```
flatpak install flathub net.sourceforge.Hugin
```

Run using:

```
flatpak run net.sourceforge.Hugin
```

Auxiliary programs can be run with:

```
flatpak run --command=align_image_stack net.sourceforge.Hugin --help
flatpak run --command=enblend net.sourceforge.Hugin --help
flatpak run --command=enfuse net.sourceforge.Hugin --help
```

Scripts to simplify running commands can be created in `~/.local/bin`.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
flatpak run --command=enblend net.sourceforge.Hugin "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hugin is compiled as a flatpak and if you do not have flatpak installed and do not wish to install flatpak, you can use the appimage version.
Information from the http://hugin.sourceforge.net/download/ page.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer.
The appimage runs under ubuntu 20.04, unfortunately not under ubuntu 22.04 :-(

I'm trying to compile it now...